# How to remove the pause during JBoss 5.1.0 GA boot between ProfileServiceBootstrap and AnnotationCreator?

Tags: boot, jboss, performance-tuning

I've managed to strip down my JBoss profile enough that it boots in 1.5 minutes. I started with the **web** profile and started pulling out stuff I didn't need. The bulk of my boot time can be seen here:

```
...
15:21:51,890 INFO  [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Loading profile: ProfileKey@86d597[domain=default, server=default, name=np]
15:22:55,406 WARN  [AnnotationCreator] No ClassLoader provided, using TCCL: org.jboss.managed.api.annotation.ManagementComponent
15:22:55,578 WARN  [AnnotationCreator] No ClassLoader provided, using TCCL: org.jboss.managed.api.annotation.ManagementComponent
...
```

Does anyone have any idea what JBoss is doing here for 1 minute? If so, is there any way to speed it up or skip it entirely?

This is for developer instances, so boot time is quite important.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `DEBUG` or `TRACE` for `org.jboss` in  `conf/jboss-log4j.xml` and see.